# Chef Check Package is already installed

Tags: chef-infra, devops, chef-recipe

**Recipe**

`cookbook_file '/tmp/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip' do
  source 'awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
  notifies :run, "bash[install_awscli]", :immediately
end`

`bash "install_awscli" do
  user "root"
  cwd "/tmp"
  code <<-EOH
    unzip awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip
    (sudo ./aws/install && aws --version)
  EOH
  action :nothing
end`

**Error**
`an "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20200510-1596-1thl7p2" returned 1`

My question is that what is the proper way to check if a certain package is already install so that it will not be re installed from the recipe?

Comment: Your cookbook_file resource should handle this correctly - the only thing, consider using directory other than /tmp for it - in case you're cleaning up /tmp frequently. If you would include more information regarding error you're getting - i.e. larger log - would be useful. Also are you by chance trying to also install aws cli outside of chef?

Comment: I see I did transfer the installer file into persistent directory that fixes the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the directory from `/tmp` into some persistent directory solve the issue..